# how to change name of form parameter in fancytree

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I'm using Fancytree jquery plugin to manage a tree structure in a form.

I've used the example code like this to submit the values from within a form:

```
$("#parent").fancytree("getTree").generateFormElements();
var formData = $form.serializeArray();
```

It works well except I want to change the name of the parameter which is default to ft_1[]. Is there a configuration or a way to change this parameter name to a user defined one?

Answer (score 0):

`generateFormElements(selected, active)` accepts boolean or strings a arguments.

If a string is passed, it is interpreted as element name:

```
$("#parent").fancytree("getTree").generateFormElements("selectedVar", "activeVar");
var formData = $form.serializeArray();
```

Comment: thanks I tried it, but $("#parent").fancytree("getTree").generateFormElements('parentCategoriesList', 'parentCategoriesList'); - still generates ft_1[] in the form parameters.

Comment: Seems you found a bug, I will look into it: https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/403

Comment: No worries, thanks, for now I just used selectedItems and added the form data manually.